# Background task not running

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, background-task

I'm trying to check some `HealthKit` data in the background and send a local notification if certain criteria were met.

I've added Background fetch capability and added my task's id to `info.plist`.

here is the background task code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // other setups

        self.setupHealthKit()

        self.setupBackgroundTasks()
        
        return true
    }

fileprivate func setupHealthKit() {
        
        HealthKitHelper.shared.executeObserverQuery(for: HealthKitTypes.activeEnergy,
                                                predicate: nil)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {
            completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("observer query execution failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                EventLogger.BackgroundDelivery.logObserverQueryError(error: error.localizedDescription)
            case .finished:
                print("observer query executed.")
            }
        }, receiveValue: {
            query, handler in
            // we have some updates
            
            EventLogger.BackgroundDelivery.logObserverQueryResultInBackground()
            
            // check if there is a new sleep session
            
            let queue = OperationQueue()
            
            let operations = self.getBackgroundOperations()
            
            let last = operations.last!
            last.completionBlock = {
                handler()
            }
            
            queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
            
        })
        .store(in: &self.subscriberStore)
        
        HealthKitHelper.shared.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: HealthKitTypes.activeEnergy,
                                                        frequency: .hourly)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("failed to enable bg delivery with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .finished:
                    print("delivery enable finished.")
                }
            }, receiveValue: {
                status in
                print("delivery enable success status: \(status)")
            })
            .store(in: &self.subscriberStore)
        
    }
    
func setupBackgroundTasks() {
        
        let status = BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: self.BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK_ID,
                                                     using: nil) {
            task in
            
            self.handleBackgroundAppRefresh(task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
            
        }
        
    }
```

I'm just sending a local notification in my background task to see if it works.
now I'm able to run the background task in the debugger, but it never gets executed by the system.

And I also don't know what's the best way to get new health kit samples in the background.

Comment: Any luck solving the problem? Having the same issue here..

Comment: I stopped using combine for background tasks and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *HKObserverQuery* to query health data in the background.

Comment: I'm already using `HKObserverQuery` but it's not being called. I'll add my code to the question.